# pause and resume specific requests in Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I want some type of requests to be paused in Glide. But I tried and it pauses all requests. I have `Recyclerview` with items which have 2 different images. I want to pause requests for one type of images only. Is it possible?

Comment: Don't think it's directly possible, you'll have to hack around with separate context (child fragments?) for each type of request. Then the request manager tied to those individual fragments can be paused and resumed.

Comment: @TWiStErRob , thanks for the reply. Actually, the requests of the second type are embedded in the first one as a thumbnail requests. The final goal is to pause full image loading without pausing thumbnail loading. For smooth scrolling experience in low-end devices. I thought it would be hard to separate request from its thumbnail() and decided to load thumbnails separately. Which is also not so good idea but still... thanks anyway

Comment: In that case, priority may be enough, wouldn't it? Have you tried setting the thumbnails higher priority? (Thinkinkg more, they may actually be automatically higher.)

Comment: Yes I tried nearly everything. Problem is that device is so slow rendering full sized bitmap halts scrolling speed for a second. Or half of a second. Only safe time to load full sized bitmap is when scrolling is stopped (state_idle) I'm sharing screen recording of Airbnb app which has the behavior I want. This recording is on S8 so no need for optimized loading, but Airbnb app on low-end device only loads images when scrolling is stopped or maybe 2-5 pixels per second. You can see in recording that thumbnails are always loaded before full image. This creates great user experience

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sdVorNvmgch4Zl8wE6GF48jQPG9NrhzV/view?usp=drivesdk link here

Comment: I should also mention that I'm using glides listview preloader to make loading faster. And it works great. But on low-end device only thing that worked was loading only when idle. I think older devices have some issues about GPU or something

Comment: Just setting a full size bitmap shouldn't cause jank, maybe it causes a re-layout (try to fix the size of views), or try to decrease the Bitmap size, AirBnB's thumbnails look like 16x16 or similarly low quality and make sure your "full size" is not `SIZE_ORIGINAL`. They must also have bucketed requests, so the amount of bytes on the wire is minimised.

Comment: Tried fixing sizes. Same. Full size isn't original size , I use override () with exact sizes in pixels . My thumbnails are viewSize/50 (small enough) . Amount of bytes isn't important. I have also optimized loading from server. Depending on density, server sends 6 different sizes.

Comment: What if I fork Glide repo and add this functionality? Meaning that user will be able to pause full and thumbnail requests separately? Is it a good idea?

Comment: Open a GitHub issue and talk to sjudd (Sam) there. Link to this SO question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I really appreciate your help